# How to set sysdate variable in the .json object?

Tags: javascript, json, testing, postman, postman-pre-request-script

I have a post .json method where I send an object:

```
{
"targetSigningDate": "2021-09-22T21:00:00.000Z"
}
```

The "*targetSigningDate*" must always be '**sysdate**'. Instead of manualy chaning the date, how to set sysdate into the object using pre-req. script ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What `.json` method? Also JSON should be sent as a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out by creating a pre-request script where I set a variable 'moment' and then set it to the environment

looks like this:

```
{
    var moment = require('moment')
    pm.environment.set("sysdate", moment())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON format [does not expect a sysdate type value](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), so it won't be parsed as sysdate by parsers. You should do it programmatically yourself instead.